# Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'none'"

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, content-security-policy, vercel, stripes

#### I have a huge problem with this error and I can't seem to stop it from showing.

**Disclaimer: I am still a junior and I am still getting to know NextJS in detail, so pardon me if made some mistakes along with asking this question.*

I am using the latest version of `NextJS` (at the time of asking the question) and I am deploying it to `vercel`

I get this error that is spammed 50 or so times
[image]

### The things I tried.

##### 1. I added a meta tag to the `<Head />` element in `_app.tsx` that looks like this

```
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="font-src * 'unsafe-inline';"
/>
```

(i misspelled the `content` property several times and it gave me an error, so I know it is working, I am using `font-src * 'unsafe-inline', because it was said, that it allowed all sources)
**BUT the error persists**

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/font-src

#### 2. I added headers to `next.config.js`

```
...
const securityHeaders = [
  {
    key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
    value: `font-src * 'unsafe-inline';`,
  },
]
module.exports = withImages({
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // Apply these headers to all routes in your application.
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: securityHeaders,
      },
    ]
  },
...
```

The error keeps showing. If i set this header to `font-src 'self'` or `font-src https://js.stripe.com`. I get a different error above this one, that states *local font refused to load because it violates font-src https://js.stripe.com*

source: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/security-headers

#### 3. I added `vercel.json`

A colleague of mine suggested that this might be a vercel error, so I added this to the file

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "headers": {
        "content-security-policy-report-only": "font-src * 'unsafe-inline';"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

source: https://app.rapidsec.com/docs/deploying-csp

Still, the error persists

### Actual question.

Should I keep up trying with these security headers, or is it a dead-end? Is it a vercel error, or a nextjs one as it happens only on the server? Or should I just try and override the class that assigns these fonts to go around this error.
P.S. when I open the link in the error, it gives me `Error 404`, and this is the official stripe dependency `stripe: "^8.195.0`

Comment: You can find specific details regarding Content Security Policies & Stripe.js here:
https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser extension called Ultrawidify was causing the issue. As it scans the site for videos (why, i don't know. I thought it only worked on youtube) it tries to access stripe.com as it was listed in the "Choose which site to control" list. Turning off the extension for the site did nothing, it still gave that error, but disabling it completely fixed the issue,

Answer (score 2):

After trying to solve the problem for some time, I decided to see if any of my extensions was the cause, as mentioned in some comments. For me, it was the Pop up blocker for Chrome - Poper Blocker. After disabling the extension, the CSP error no longer appears.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that a content security policy is already set on your site. All content need to pass all policies, so adding another policy won't help. You need to identify where the existing policy is set and modify from "font-src 'none';" to "font-src js.stripe.com;".

Comment: I thought it was something like this, but i found no other place that contans CSP. I will be digging into it today, hope i find something. But this is not the first NextJS project that does this. In fact it is the third. That makes me think that this is a default setting, that sits somewhere unnoticed

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong stripe keys to access stripe api. API keys identify the application or project that's calling an API. So, stripe api is not recognizing your application

also sometimes chrome extensions causes that error

Comment: no, stripe is working fine. i think that the above answer is a step in the right direction, but i dont know where the directory is, ill be investigating.

Comment: are u getting same error on a different browser?

Comment: After the things i did (above in the question) i was onl getting it in chrome. Now that i read your comment, I tried in incognito mode and there was no error, so i turned off all of my extensions one by one and found that an youtube ultrawidify extension was causing the issue... why I don't know, but..That solved my issue.

Comment: so it is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration on your next.config.js

```
const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
  font-src 'self' js.stripe.com;
  
`
```